# Calculating the Local Ternary Pattern of an depth image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I found the detail and implementation of Local Ternary Pattern (LTP) on [Calculating the Local Ternary Pattern of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191047/calculating-the-local-ternary-pattern-of-an-image/28535964?noredirect=1#comment45386491_28535964). I want to ask more details that what the best way to choose the threshold `t` and also I have confusion in understand the role of `reorder_vector = [8 7 4 1 2 3 6 9];`

Comment: If you refer to the LTP post that you're linking in your post, I made a few mistakes in that code.  That's what you get for not testing what you write.  I have modified my code to reflect those changes.  I've also added in a bit more explanation as I missed a vital step in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good way to figure out what the threshold is using LTPs.  It's mostly trial and error or by experimentation.  However, I could suggest to make the threshold adaptive.  You can use [Otsu's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) to dynamically determine the best threshold of your image.  This is assuming that the distribution of your intensities in the image is bimodal.  In other words, there is a clear separation between objects and background.  MATLAB has an implementation of this by the [`graythresh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) function.  However, this generates a threshold between 0 and 1, so you will need to multiply the result by 255, assuming that the type of your image is `uint8`.

Therefore, do:

```
t = 255*graythresh(im);
```

`im` is the image that you desire to compute the LTPs.  Now, I can certainly provide insight on what the `reorder_vector` is doing.  Look at the following figure on how to calculate LTPs:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hindawi.com](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/373254.fig.004.jpg))</sub>

When we generate the ternary code matrix (matrix in the middle), we need to generate an 8 element sequence that doesn't include the middle of the neighbourhood.  We start from the east most element (row 2, column 3), then traverse the elements in counter-clockwise order.  The `reorder_vector` variable allows you to select those specific elements that respect that order.  If you recall, MATLAB can access matrices using column-major linear indices.  Specifically, given a 3 x 3 matrix, we can access an element using a number from 1 to 9 and the memory is laid out like so:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Therefore, the first element of `reorder_vector` is index 8, which is the east most element.  Next is index 7, which is the top right element, then index 4 which is the north facing element, then 1, 2, 3, 6 and finally 9.

If you follow these numbers, you will determine how I got the `reorder_vector`:

```
reorder_vector = [8 7 4 1 2 3 6 9];
```

By using this variable for accessing each 3 x 3 local neighbourhood, we would thus generate the correct 8 element sequence that respects the ordering of the ternary code so that we can proceed with the next stage of the algorithm.

Comment: I have an image patch of size `40x60` and its double type with range of values from `-0.0103 - 0.2929`. So I should first convert it into `uint8` and then calculate the threshold as you suggested `t = 255*graythresh(im);`. Also, In the MATLAB code which was provided by you in the above mentioned link, in that do we need to select the radius and other parameter like we do in LBP? and lastly, in that code the final output is `ltp_upper`, `ltp_lower `, probably these are two decimal numbers. Is it possible to get the output in term of histogram of LTP values.

Comment: @FrqKhan (1) If it's `double`, there's no need to multiply by 255.  Use the threshold right out of `graythresh` as is.  (2) I don't believe you need to select the radius or other parameters.  LTP is designed for 3 x 3 windows only.  (3).  Yes.  Simply apply `imhist` to each `ltp_upper` and `ltp_lower` to get a histogram of all LTP values for both upper and lower patterns.

Comment: OK and is it fine concatenate both the histograms at the end for the final representation..?

Comment: No idea. That's your call to make!