# Calculating the LTP of a binary image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I have an understanding of LTP based on the explanation from the original paper and the one given here: [Calculating the Local Ternary Pattern of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191047/calculating-the-local-ternary-pattern-of-an-image)

My code is working fine and is able to extract LTP from grayscale images but when I present logical images, I get nothing but all 0's in the output.

I know that people have applied LBP and LTP on binary images in literature, but I fail to understand how that is possible given the working of LTP.

I am using this implementation of LTP, that is giving excellent identification results fro grayscale, but does not work on binary images: http://dismac.dii.unipg.it/ldlbp/code/ltp.m

This is the input image I am using (binary):
[image]

and here is the upper and lower LTP output:
[image]

Comment: Maybe, you can try to use the matlab debugger and try to understand why you get this result.

Comment: what happens when you do `bw = bw*255` (when `bw` is your binary image)?

Comment: I have already used the debugger, the upper and lower LTP are calculated, as per the explanation, in this line: ``D_L = ((double(C) - double(N) - Delta) >= 0);       %LTP - lower`` and ``D_U = ((double(N) - double(C) - Delta) >= 0);       %LTP - upper``. This works for grayscae, but understandably will not work on logical images

Comment: You just need to convert your data, man... that is really trivial to do....